# No self href in embedded HAL resource collection

Tags: collections, href, embedded-resource, self, hal-json

I use the `self` `href` from my HAL resources on the client side to find the right path for the CRUD operations. In single(ton) resources this is working fine (see the address resource below, the `_links` containing the `self` `href` is included in the embedded resource) but when it comes down to collections this is a different story. The `_links` of a collection are not rendered when the collection is in `_embedded`.

Earlier I worked around this problem by reading the url form the first child. But this is not sufficient. In case the collection is empty I only have 
an empty array with no possibility to extract the url like that. If I want to create a new item in the collection I would like that my client knows where to send data using `POST` by reading the `self` `href` from `_links`. Is it a good idea to include the `_links` to my collection like this:

```php
{
    "_links": {
        "self": {
            "href": "http://example.com/api/v1/users/1"
        }
    },
    "_embedded": {
        "contacts": {
```

Now I have access to the self href here:

```php
            "_links": {
                "self": {
                    "href": "http://example.com/api/v1/users/1/contacts"
                }
            },
            "_embedded": {
                "contacts": [
                    {
                        "_links": {
                            "self": {
                                "href": "http://example.com/api/v1/users/1/contacts/2"
                            }
                        },
                        "id": "2",
                        "name": "John Smith"
                    },
                    {
                        "_links": {
                            "self": {
                                "href": "http://example.org/api/v1/users/1/contacts/3"
                            }
                        },
                        "id": "3",
                        "name": "Jane Doe"
                    }
                ],
            }
        },
        "address": {
            "_links": {
                "self": {
                    "href": "http://example.com/api/v1/addresses/1"
                }
            },
            "street": "Bakerstreet 11",
            "postal code": "123456",
            "city": "Some city",
            "country": "Some country",
        }
    },
    "id": "1",
    "name": "John Doe"
}
```

### EDIT (one year later)

In the end I solved this by always adding the links of embedded resources to the parent resource. So in the example above my response object would look like this:

```php
{
    "_links": {
        "self": {
            "href": "http://example.com/api/v1/users/1"
        },
        "contacts": {
            "href": "http://example.com/api/v1/users/1/contacts"
        },
        "address": {
            "href": "http://example.com/api/v1/addresses/1"
        }
    },
    "_embedded": {
        "contacts": [
            {
                "_links": {
                    "self": {
                        "href": "http://example.com/api/v1/users/1/contacts/2"
                    }
                },
                "id": "2",
                "name": "John Smith"
            },
            {
                "_links": {
                    "self": {
                        "href": "http://example.org/api/v1/users/1/contacts/3"
                    }
                },
                "id": "3",
                "name": "Jane Doe"
            },
        ],
        "address": {
            "_links": {
                "self": {
                    "href": "http://example.org/api/v1/addresses/1"
                }
            },
            "street": "Bakerstreet 11",
            "postal code": "123456",
            "city": "Some city",
            "country": "Some country",
        }
    },
    "id": "1",
    "name": "John Doe"
}
```

So no matter whether I embedded the resources or not I always know where they are located. And for the contacts collection I will have the link to my collection endpoint in the `_links` array and the contacts themselves in `_embedded`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. It's not only good practice to do so; it's [recommended by the HAL spec](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-kelly-json-hal-06#section-8.1):

> Each Resource Object SHOULD contain a 'self' link that corresponds with the IANA registered 'self' relation (as defined by RFC5988) whose target is the resource's URI.

A collection of resources is itself a resource, don't forget.